# remove number at the end from text column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Name column in program table. And it has the following values

```
Name

Style U.
Music Videos (60)        108
Amp                      111
MTV2 JAMS                112
RoR                      113
Artist Collection        114
```

My requirement is to remove the numbers part appearing at the end of the above data.
If no number is present, then I need the value as it is from the Select query.

I have tried with the following logic..

```
DECLARE @c AS VARCHAR(25)
SET @c = 'abc3 hkh  360'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@c)), 0) = 0 
        THEN @c 
        ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@c)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@c)), -1))
    END AS Prg_Name
```

Result: abc3

But the problem in above logic is that, it is not able to find the 2 continuous spaces and instead it is trimming whenever it is finding first space.

Comment: What's your expected result given your sample data?

Comment: My expected result for above variable @C is 'abc3 hkh'. that is remove the number part at the end

Comment: Is it always a three digit number and have you considered a one off job to split name in to two columns, you don't want to be doing this all the time..

Comment: No it need not to be 3 digit number always.. it can change.. but rule says if the word find 3 continuos space then trim the further part

Comment: Thanks All.. but problem is solved.. :) declare @c as varchar(25)
set @c='abc3 tc  152'

select case when patindex('%  %',ltrim(rtrim(@c)))=0 then @C
else
SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(@c)),1,patindex('%  %',ltrim(rtrim(@c)))) end as Prg_Name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All.. but problem is solved.. :)

```
declare @c as varchar(25) 
set @c='abc3 tc 152' 
select 
    case when patindex('% %',ltrim(rtrim(@c)))=0 
        then @C 
        else SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(@c)),1,patindex('% %',ltrim(rtrim(@c)))) 
end as Prg_Name
```